# WPF : Focus delay when clicked away and back to the app

Tags: .net, wpf, memory, datagrid

I have a datagrid inside the WPF application and I need to have it very responsive so that the user can work on one screen with Excel and on the other screen work with WPF application's datagrid.

When I click away from my WPF application to Excel and click back to the WPF application, there is a light half-second delay before the app is focused again.

What could be the cause for this delay? What can I do to reduce or eliminate this delay?

Your help on this is highly appreciated,

Comment: How much data does the grid have? Is grid virtualization turned on? How many updates is the grid pushing through? If you have a busy UI thread this will make this an unresponsive app...move stuff onto background thread etc.

Comment: as a test to see if the grid rendering is causing it. Make the DataGrid ReadOnly, then try...

Comment: A possible way to find the cause: start the application under a profiler and make the problematic clicks many times (30+), and then in the profiler look at the hot spots so see a stack trace leading to the cause.